# When we can use L'Hopital's Rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If we are proving that a limit goes to 0, can we use L'Hopital's Rule?

Namely, I am trying to prove that f' exists, where $f(x)=(1/x)e^{-1/x^2}$, at 0. I am using the definition of derivative, and by substituting y=1/x, I want to show that $\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{e^{y^2}}$ is 0. Can I use L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: You can, but you'd do better in posting the statement of the L'Hôpital Rule here so someone can guide you through it.

Comment: First of all, it needs to be an indeterminate expression of $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ type.
Both parts of the fraction have to be continuously differentiable (from the side you are calculating the limit from) and both limits must exist.

Comment: I assume your looking for $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac {f(x)} x$ which is $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac {e^{-1/x^2}} x$, otherwise your substitution would not be correct.  If so, then it works beautifully.

Comment: Yes, I am. Thank you (I edited it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are taking the limit of a quotient, $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$, in which the numerator and denominator are differentiable on the interval ($\mathbb{I}\backslash c$) containing the limit approaching the limit but the limits of both are both $0$ or both $\pm\infty$, you may apply l'Hopital's rule.

If:

1. $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to c} g(x) = 0 \;\lor\; \lim\limits_{x\to c} |f(x)| = \lim\limits_{x\to c} |g(x)| = \infty$
2. $g(x) \neq 0 , \forall x \in \mathbb{I}\backslash c, x \neq c$
3. $\exists \lim\limits_{x \to c} \dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$

Then:

- $\lim\limits_{x\to c} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} =  \lim\limits_{x\to c} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

---

As you've noticed, the choice of denominator and numerator impacts how useful l'Hopital's rule becomes.  Your substitution technique is a very nice tool.

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac {e^{-1/{x^2}}}{x}$ satisfies these conditions, but $\dfrac{\operatorname{d} e^{-1/x^2}}{\operatorname{d} x} = \dfrac{2 e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}$ so applying l'Hopital's rule just makes things worse!

But by substituting $y=\frac 1 x$ you obtain $\lim\limits_{y\to \infty} \dfrac {y}{e^{(y^2)}}$, which also satisfies the conditions, *and* the derivatives are cleaner.  This produces quite an elegant solution.

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac {e^{-1/{x^2}}}{x} = \lim\limits_{y\to \infty} \dfrac {y}{e^{y^2}} \quad \text{by substitution: } y=\frac 1 x \\\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac {e^{-1/{x^2}}}{x} = \lim\limits_{y\to \infty} \dfrac {1}{2 y e^{(y^2)}} \quad \text{by l'H}\!\mathop{\text{o}}^{..}\!\text{pital's rule} \\ \therefore \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \dfrac {e^{-1/{x^2}}}{x} = 0$